# Is there a generalization of the homotopy version of Cauchy's Theorem to several complex variables?

Tags: complex-analysis, stokes-theorem, cauchy-principal-value

In Cauchy's Theorem there are two homotopic paths in $\mathbb{C}$ with the same endpoints (the homotopy leaving both endpoints fixed).
There is an analytic function $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$
and the integral over both paths is the same.

I can imagine a generalization, where there are two homotopic maps from
the square $[0,1]^2$ to $\mathbb{C}^2$ (the homotopy leaving the boundary of the square fixed), defining two "patches".
And there is an analytic function $\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$.
The integral of the function over both "patches" is the same.

If there is such a generalization, then is it really a form of Stokes Theorem ?

The particular integral I'm interested in is the
complex inversion formula for the multivariate Laplace Transform.
This formula is a limit of an integral over "patches" centered at $0$ that grow arbitrarily large.

Thank you in advance...